check if class instance forwarded by reference is member of abstract class
Using BLoC as state management, I want to check if an event forwarded to another widget belongs to a certain BLoC abstract class. The reason is that I am using a form containing widget for 2 different use cases / BLoCs and depending on the BLoC I need to use a different event. There is also a minor other difference between the use cases which is why I would like to identify the use case by the event passed when calling the widget. Sure, I could also pass a bool with that info, but then thought why not recognizing the abstract class of the event.
So let's assume I have
abstract class EditEvent extends Equatable {
  const EditEvent();
}

class EditItemDeselected extends EditEvent {
  EditItemDeselected(this.outerIdx, this.innerIdx);
  final int outerIdx, innerIdx;
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [outerIdx, innerIdx];
}

abstract class EditMasterEvent extends Equatable {
  const EditMasterEvent();
}

class EditMasterItemDeselected extends EditMasterEvent {
  EditMasterItemDeselected(this.outerIdx, this.innerIdx);
  final int outerIdx, innerIdx;
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [outerIdx, innerIdx];
}

Then, in some widget I call the child widget with
ChildWidget(itemSelectedEvent: (int i, int j) => EditItemDeselected(i, j))
with the parameter in ChildWidget declared as final Function(int, int) itemSelectedEvent;
Now, inside ChildWidget something like if (itemSelectedEvent is EditEvent) does not work, neither does if (itemSelectedEvent is EditItemDeselected). It always results in false.
The debugger shows for itemSelectedEvent the value {_Closure} Closure: (int, int) => EditItemDeselected 

What is the definition for JobEditTaskDeselected? Why do you want to use type checking instead of polymorphism?

sorry, corrected this now to EditItemDeselected in the snippet. Was a copy paste mistake... EditItemDeselected is then defined above. What do you mean with polymorphism in this context? Not sure how I could apply this here

Since you declared itemSelectedEvent as dynamic Function(int, int) itemSelectedEvent is EditEvent will always return false since itemSelectedEvent is a Function and not an EditEvent.
You need to call the function to get the return type. If you set itemSelectedEvent to (int i, int j) => EditItemDeselected(i, j) itemSelectedEvent(1, 2) is EditEvent will return true.
Note: type checking is considered a bad practice in OOP. Because the switch cases need to be duplicated accross the code and if you add new types you need to adjust all of them.
class ChildWidget {
  ChildWidget(this.itemSelectedEvent);

  final Function(int, int) itemSelectedEvent;

  void func(int i1, int i2) {
    if (itemSelectedEvent(i1, i2) is EditEvent) {
      // do if EditEvent
    }
    if (itemSelectedEvent(i1, i2) is EditMasterEvent ) {
      // do if EditMasterEvent
    }
  }
}

Consider this instead:
abstract class EditEvent extends Equatable {
  const EditEvent();

  void doStuff();
}

class EditItemDeselected extends EditEvent {
  EditItemDeselected(this.outerIdx, this.innerIdx);
  final int outerIdx, innerIdx;

  void doStuff() {
    // do if EditEvent
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [outerIdx, innerIdx];
}

class EditMasterItemDeselected extends EditEvent {
  EditMasterItemDeselected(this.outerIdx, this.innerIdx);
  final int outerIdx, innerIdx;

  void doStuff() {
    // do if EditMasterEvent
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [outerIdx, innerIdx];
}

class ChildWidget {
  ChildWidget(this.itemSelectedEvent);

  final Function(int, int) itemSelectedEvent;

  void func(int i1, int i2) {
    itemSelectedEvent(i1, i2).doStuff()
  }
}


Thanks! Nice idea to put functionality into the BLoC event. I was so used just passing data with the event from the widget to the BLoC that I never thought about adding any functionality there.
